# Editing method comment template in Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: templates, netbeans, documentation-generation, comments

When I create a method comment in Netbeans by typing `/**` + ENTER I get something like this

```
/**
 *
 * @param nameOfParam
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
```

but in my case I like comments looking like this

```
/**
 * 
 * @param 
 *     nameOfParam - 
 * @return

 * @throws SQLException
 */
```

So I need to change this template but I can't find where. I can change every single behavior of Netbeans besides this one.

Can somebody help?

Comment: I think it's hardcoded... at least for now.  I would file an enhancement request at http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Comment: @TheAlchemist I feel it is more important to solicit people to file the enhancement requests on their own, when they have one.  This will ensure they will learn it and also tell this to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method comment templates cannot be customized to the level which is expected in this question.  These customization features can be added to the NetBeans IDE and there is a specific way how this can be done as the NetBeans IDE is an open source project working in open source way of development.  The typical steps to ask the developers to add this feature in NetBeans IDE will be

1. Log an enhancement request [RFE] in the [NetBeans IDE issue tracker](http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html)
2. Notify the community about your RFE by writing mail to the [NetBeans IDE users mailing list (users)](http://netbeans.org/community/lists/index.html) and asking all to vote for your request
3. According to the votes the RFE will get lined up for development in the next release cycle.